# Declaring a type as a subset of a set

Tags: delphi, set

I can easily declare a enumeration and a set.
But sometimes I want to work with only part of the enumeration and I'd like the compiler to check for me if values in the sub-enum and its subset stay within the bounds.

```
type
  TDay = (mon, tue, wen, thu, fri, sat, sun);
  TWeekday = (mon..fri); //not allowed;

  TDays = set of TDay;
  TWeekdays = set of TDay[mon..fri]; //not allowed
```

Can I declare `TWeekday` and `TWeekdays` as a derivative of TDay, if so, how?

<sub>Funny enough google does not yield anything (for me) on this issue, just plain old sets.</sub>

Comment: `TWeekday = mon..fri`, `TWeekdays = set of TWeekday` ?

Comment: Yes, that does the trick, I knew it was possible, but could not remember the correct syntax.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You've got the wrong syntax for the subrange. Drop the brackets `()` and it will work.

```
type
  TDay = (mon, tue, wen, thu, fri, sat, sun);
  TWeekday = mon..fri; // A subrange of TDay

  TDays = set of TDay;
  TWeekdays = set of TWeekDay;
```

More about [Subrange Types](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Simple_Types#Subrange_Types) and [Sets](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Structured_Types#Sets).