# Subset is incompatible with its superset

Tags: delphi, set

Follow-up question for: [Declaring a type as a subset of a set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29819590/declaring-a-type-as-a-subset-of-a-set)

```
program Project31; {$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

type
  TDay = (mon, tue, wen, thu, fri, sat, sun);
  TWeekday = mon..fri;

  TDays = set of TDay;
  TWeekdays = set of TWeekday;

  TDayRec = record
    Data: TDays;
    WeekendData: string;
    class operator Add(const A: TDayRec; B: TWeekday): TDayRec;
  end;

class operator TDayRec.Add(const A: TDayRec; B: TWeekday): TDayRec;
begin
  Result:= A;
  Result.Data:= Result.Data + B;  <<--E2008 Incompatible types
  Result.Data:= Result.Data + TDay(B);  <<--E2008 Incompatible types
end;

begin
end.
```

How do I get `TWeekday(s)` to be compatible with `TDay(s)`.
Casting a `TWeekday` to a `TDay` does not work.

Comment: Your `Data` member is a set, so `Result.Data := Result.Data + [B];`

Comment: Need more coffee, brain seems to be load-shedding.

Comment: Embarcadero should really overload the `+` operator to allow an ordinal to be added to a set. It seems so silly to have to "setify" the ordinal before adding it to the set.

Comment: @Johan That would allow a more natural function style instead of the horrid and clunky procedural `Include`.

Comment: I can easily declare a class helper to do just that, http://delphi.about.com/od/objectpascalide/a/delphi-record-helpers-for-sets-and-other-simple-types.htm but I need compiler intrinsics to avoid having to type cast all over the place.

Comment: Johan, for inspiration, see [Finding common elements in two arrays](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19524788/576719).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have two options. You can use the [set union operator](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Expressions_(Delphi)#Set_Operators) `+` which requires both operands to be compatible sets.

```
Result.Data:= Result.Data + [B];
```

Or you can use the [intrinsic](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Delphi_Intrinsic_Routines) procedure [`Include`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Include).

```
Include(Result.Data, B);
```

Because the `Include` operator adds a single element to the set, it is able to generate more efficient code than the union operator.